# Padding printf for Strings by 0

Tags: c, printf

Is there a way to replace the space character to 0 in printf padding for field width

Code used

```
printf("%010s","this");
```

Doesnt seem to work for strings!!

Comment: You mean padding in `printf`, not `scanf`, don't you?

Comment: Technically, the `0` modifier says, “For other conversions (*not numeric, e.g. %s*), the behavior is undefined.” I believe old versions of HPUX (and maybe some other System V Unices) would actually do this for (or against) you, where Linux and BSD typically don't…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, the `0` flag only works for numeric conversions.  You will have to do this by hand:

```
int print_padleftzeroes(const char *s, size_t width)
{
    size_t n = strlen(s);
    if(width < n)
        return -1;
    while(width > n)
    {
        putchar('0');
        width--;
    }
    fputs(s, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A version with less typing: `printf("%.*s%s", n >= 10 ? 0 : (int)(10-n), "0000000000", s);`

Comment: This really helps. Thank you, zwol.

Answer (score 4):

what about

```
 test="ABCD"
 printf "%0$(expr 9 - ${#test})d%s" 0 $test
```

that will give you what you need too.

```
 ~:00000ABCD
```

or is you want to padd with other numbers just change

```
  printf "%0$(expr 9 - ${#test})d%s" 1 $test
```

will give you

```
 ~:11111ABCD
```

Comment: Nice, but thats not C

Comment: Found it during search for shell solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
printf("%010d%s", 0, "this");
```

Comment: That will print `0000000000` then the string; OP wanted a total of 10 characters

Answer (score -1):

for golang try this (can be translated to C):

```
str := "this"
printf("0000000000"[:10-len(str)] + str)
```

Comment: It's not obvious (at least, not to me) how this would be translated into C - which is what the question asks about.